# Local variables in Python timeit setup

Tags: python, string, variables, scope, timeit

In all of the places I read about timeit I found only that I can use variables in this way:

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'abc'
timeit.timeit('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import s1, s2', number=10**4)
```

or

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'abc'
def func():
    timeit.time('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import s1,s2', number=10**4)
```

which means that you can also use timeit.timeit in a function as long as the variables are in the main program.
**I would like to use timeit.timeit with variables that are within the scope it is in, for example**:

```
def func():
    s1 = 'abc'
    s2 = 'abc'
    timeit.timeit(...)
```

As you can see my question is:

How can I use timeit.timeit with the variables that are in the same scope, when they're both not in the main program?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **I would like to use timeit.timeit with variables that are within the scope it is in.**

**TLDR:**

Use a `lambda` closure (so called because it closes over the variables in the function):

```
def func():
    s1 = 'abc'
    s2 = 'abc'
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: s1 == s2)
```

And I think that's just about what you're asking for.

```
>>> func()
0.12512516975402832
```

**Explanation**

So in the global scope, you want to use the globals, and local scope, locals? On the global scope, `locals()` returns the same as `globals()`, so it you `', '.join(locals())` and stick that on the end of `'from __main__ import '`, or `globals()` as they're equivalent on the global scope:

```
>>> s1 = 'abc'
>>> s2 = 'abc'
>>> timeit.timeit('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()))
0.14271061390928885
```

You could do this with a function and the `globals()` too, but you can't use locals():

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'abc'
def func():
    return timeit.timeit('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()))
```

and

```
>>> func()
0.14236921612231157
```

but the below doesn't work, because you've got to have access to the variables hidden in the local scope of the function, from the import statement:

```
def func():
    s1 = 'abc'
    s2 = 'abc'
    return timeit.timeit('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(locals()))
```

But because you can simply pass the function to timeit, what you *can* do is this:

```
def func(s1='abc', s2='abc'):
    s1 == s2
```

and

```
>>> timeit.timeit(func)
0.14399981498718262
```

So that also means, in your func, you can provide timeit a lambda closure:

```
def func():
    s1 = 'abc'
    s2 = 'abc'
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: s1 == s2)
```

Or a full function def:

```
def func():
    s1 = 'abc'
    s2 = 'abc'
    def closure():
        return s1 == s2
    return timeit.timeit(closure)
```

And I think that's just about what you're asking for.

```
>>> func()
0.12512516975402832
```

> **When they're both not in the main program**

If you want to join the globals instead with a setup, from other modules than `__main__`, use this:

```
'from ' + __name__ + ' import ' + ', '.join(globals())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As jonrsharpe has explained, there's no (straightforward) way for a function running on the `timeit` scope to access [something outside its scope that is not a global](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php).

You should consider rewriting your function to take the variables it needs to use as arguments - **using globals is generally considered a bad practice that leads to a lot of problems**.

In order to provide the arguments to `timeit.timeit`, you can use a [partial function](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Partial_functions):

```
from functools import partial

def func(s1,s2):
    pass

timeit.timeit( partial( func, s1='bla', s2='bla' ) )
```